# Position text inside ahref element (in center of image)

Tags: css, magento2.4, static-block

I created a static block with the following issue:

I'm trying to center text inside an ahref element, which looks like the following;

```
    <div class="small-24 medium-16 cell">
    <a title="Chairs" href="/chairs"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/chair-1.png"}}" alt="Chairs" width="830" height="325">Chairs</a>
    </div>
```

Normally, I would position it as follows, with the text in a span in the ahref element next to the img:

```
a {
   position: relative;
}
span {
position: absolute;
bottom: 10px;
left: 10px;
}
```

However, I'm not allowed to save the span tag inside the ahref element next to the image. See image underneath.
[image]

How can I position the text inside the ahref element over the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the width and height on the **img** and define it in your css instead. Set image to position: absolute. Make the **a tag** a flex box and center align elements both vertically and horizontally.

```
<div class="small-24 medium-16 cell">
    <a title="Chairs" href="/chairs">
        <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/chair-1.png"}}" alt="Chairs">Chairs
    </a>
</div>



a {
    position: relative;
    width: 830px;
    height: 325px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

a img {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Note that adding `width` and `height` attributes to the image itself can help with improving CLS scores for Google's performance metrics

Comment: Not sure how that applies to position absolute though